# How to emit signals with parameters

Tags: python, parameters, pyqt4, signals-slots

My first question about this topic was [QtCore.SIGNALS not working on my code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36486565/984421).

But how to run this function two times with different parameters? For example:

first time argument = 0

n[0]

second time argument = 1

n[1]

```
    def view_splash(self, argument):
        print('test')
        label = QLabel("<font color=red size=10<b>" + n[argument] + "</b></font>")
        label.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        label.show()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, label.close)


class AThread(QtCore.QThread):
    trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def run(self):
        print('n[0]')
        self.trigger.emit()
        time.sleep(10)
        print('n[1]')
        self.trigger.emit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the signal with the parameter types you want to send:

```
class AThread(QtCore.QThread):
    trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
```

Then emit the actual values:

```
    def run(self):
        print('n[0]')
        self.trigger.emit(0)
        time.sleep(10)
        print('n[1]')
        self.trigger.emit(1)
```